# Problem in Developing for multiple screen resolution in Android?

Tags: android, screen, resolution

I want to develop Android applications which will support multiple screen resolutions. I have gone through support multiple screen resolution article.

I tried creating folder layout-hdpi and had one layout file in that. The layout file with similar name was in layout folder too. I changed certain values in layout file which was in layout-hdpi but that also changed the values in layout file which was in layout folder.

To be more specific the hierarchy is something like this

res
|
-->layout
|
--------> main.xml
|
-->layout-hdpi
|
--------> main.xml

Any change in the main.xml under layout-hdpi also changes the value in main.xml under layout.

Can someone let me know why is this happening?

Comment: just forgot layout-hdpi, create layout-large folder under res directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue, I think you copied the actual layout and pasted it in other directory, some how IDEs map copied files and when you save them changes applies on all the copies.

Try restarting the IDE and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

To have different layout files for different screen sizes, you have to name your folders like that:

```
res/layout/main.xml            // layout for normal screen size
res/layout-small/main.xml      // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/main.xml      // layout for large screen siz
```

Just look at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: If you look at the table that is given in that link layout-large will be used for mdpi with large screens. What about the hdpi devices they will be reading the main.xml under layout folder. What I want is to have different xml for hdpi devices.

Comment: I even tried creating layout-large folder under res and put main.xml inside it. The problem that is coming is that if I change anything in main.xml under layout-large then it also changes the main.xml which is under layout. This two are separate files and should not get changed. Is there any reason of such behavior?